# Animation Frames

Tags: animation, keyframes, frame-rate

I'm a bit confused with the frames when it comes to animation and how many there are in a second etc. Could someone break it down and explain it? I've read something about it needing to be divided by 10 or something. Why is this? All I know is that the default 250 frames equals 10 seconds of video/animation, but I don't understand how/why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### default: 24 fps

By default there are 24 animation frames in a second, therefore the default 250 frames equal to 10.42 seconds (250 divided by 24). There are proposals to make the length of the default blender file equal to 240, in order to have an exact duration of 10 seconds.

To know how many frames you need to create an animation of a given length, just multiply the duration (in seconds) by 24, and change "*Frame End*" accordingly.

<sup>*e.g.* 1 minute = 60 seconds → frames = 60 x 24 = 1440</sup>

<sup>4 seconds → frames = 4 x 24 = 96.</sup>

#### other frame rates

24 frames per second (24fps) has been the standard for films since the 1930s. With modern technology, it's now more and more common to see video shot at 30fps or 60fps.

The frame rate can be changed from the *Render* panel in Blender up to 2.79 (in the *Output* panel in Blender 2.8), under "***Frame Rate***":

[image] [image]

Since blender animations are frame-based, changing the frame rate will change the time length of the animation, while the keyframes will remain bound to their original frame. The frame rate should be chosen before starting an animation project.

Comment: Yeah, that I'm all familiar with. :) I'm just trying to get my head around how it's all worked out so I know how many frames to set my project to in order to get the right amount of seconds or minutes of animation/video. For my current project, I just need a 4 second idle animation.

Comment: Just multiply the duration (in seconds) by 24. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to get it. Thanks. Much appreciated. :D

Comment: Also, in the timeline, you can go to View → Sow Seconds (or hit Ctrl T). This way the timeline will display the time in second, as well as the frames between seconds. Be also aware that you can write simple maths in blender. If you want an animation of 32.5 seconds, you can write the maths according to your framerate in the end frame field : `32.5*24`